# WARNING Configuring `gql_build:serializer_builder` in target `WelcomeApp: WelcomeApp` but this is not a known Builder

Tags: flutter, graphql

I am trying to use Ferry with Flutter using the official documentation . I have placed my schema.graphql into my project and it has auto generated the necessary files, which has enabled me to extract my first query Login no problem.

I have created a build.yaml file to which I have posted the following code....

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      gql_build|schema_builder:
        enabled: true
      gql_build|ast_builder:
        enabled: true
      gql_build|data_builder:
        enabled: true
        options:
          schema: WelcomeApp|lib/schema.graphql
      gql_build|var_builder:
        enabled: true
        options:
          schema: WelcomeApp|lib/schema.graphql
      gql_build|serializer_builder:     <-------------------ERROR ON THIS LINE
        enabled: true
        options:
          schema: WelcomeApp|lib/schema.graphql

      ferry_generator|req_builder:
        enabled: true
        options:
          schema: WelcomeApp|lib/schema.graphql
```

And added my query into a file called login.graphql.

However when calling flutter

```
pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

it builds some of the autogenerated files associated with the login.schema but the login.req.gql.dart is full of errors. I believe I am missing all the files with the .g.dart extension. I receive the following error associated with line 15 in the build.yaml file....

```
[WARNING] Configuring `gql_build:serializer_builder` in target `WelcomeApp: WelcomeApp` but this is not a known Builder
```

I believe the missing files that are not being auto generated are....

login.data.gql.g.dart
login.req.gql.g.dart
login.var.gql.g.dart

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by adding gql_build in pubspec.yaml dependencies.

```
dependencies:
  ferry:
  gql_http_link:
  get: ^4.1.1
  get_storage: ^2.0.1
  get_it:
  gql_build: ^0.1.4+2

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^0.41.2`
```

Answer (score 4):

a few of the builders have been removed, see https://github.com/gql-dart/ferry/blob/master/examples/pokemon_explorer/build.yaml for latest one:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      ferry_generator|graphql_builder:
        enabled: true
        options:
          schema: pokemon_explorer|lib/schema.graphql

      ferry_generator|serializer_builder:
        enabled: true
        options:
          schema: pokemon_explorer|lib/schema.graphql
```